# Java: Use of default values

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i;
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

When I do this, even though the default value of an int is 0, it gives a compile-time error saying the variable i has not been initialized. So, what is the underlying concept here and what is the use of default values of primitives when they cannot help in cases like this?

Comment: The variable is local, try setting it as a field

Comment: Local *variables* don't have default values. Class *fields* have default values.

Comment: The underlying concept is called *definite assignment*. There's an [entire chapter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-16.html) of the language spec about it.